# Get request URL in NextJS server component inside the app folder

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js13

Is there a way to get the request object (`NextRequest`) or at least the `request URL` inside a server component (Page and/or layout components) using NextJS 13 and the new app directory?

I know how to do it in a client component, but I want to get it in a server component.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know is not possible directly access the request within a Server Component.

Actually you can get the `next-url` header using `headers().get('next-url')` but it seems quite unstable (at least on my environment).

As workaround you can use `middleware.ts` to inject custom data within the headers like:

```js
export async function Middleware(req) {
  const requestHeaders = new Headers(req.headers)
  requestHeaders.set('x-url', req.nextUrl.url)

  return NextResponse.next({
    request: {
      headers: requestHeaders
    }
  })
}
```

And then on your server component:

```js
const MyServerComponent = () => {
  const url = headers().get('x-url')
  // Stuff with the URL
}
```

Comment: this is still 100% accurate in NextJS 14. Created issue for improved docs: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/57762